# upload base64 video file using django

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a user model that i want to add a video field to it, i used Base64ImageField to upload the image for the user and PDFBase64File for the files implementing Base64FileField, so i want VIDEOBASE64File validator for the video to accept video types like mp4, ...etc

```
class PDFBase64File(Base64FileField):
    ALLOWED_TYPES = ['pdf']

    def get_file_extension(self, filename, decoded_file):
        try:
            PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(io.BytesIO(decoded_file))
        except PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError as e:
            return 'non-valid'
        return 'pdf'
```

I want a validator for the video to accept certain extension of videos.

Comment: what does your PDFBase64Field have to do with your question? Are you looking to upload PDFs or videos? And what is the issue you're facing with your code? Error?

Comment: i am showing an example for pdf validator i used .. now i am asking for one for the video

Comment: that depends what type of videos you're going to accept. The example you show for PDF is actually checking if it can decode the PDF (it doesn't just rely on the filename). Decoding video is complex. You can use **ffmpeg-python** or **opencv**.  Or just rely on the filename given by the user (and not do anything with `decoded_file`).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the binary field type on the model for your video file, see https://devdocs.io/django~2.2/ref/models/fields#django.db.models.BinaryField

in your view you should use the validator you shared to decide what field to put the binary in.